# Why can't I get the recordset directly from the stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, ado

I have a SP as follows. When I execute it with ADO, the first returned recordset is closed. I have to call the `NextRecordset` method to get the recordset I want. Why is that? How can I avoid the trouble? Thank you.

```
create proc GetTeamCurrentPlan
    @ReleaseID    varchar(30)
as

set nocount on
declare @CurrentSp smallint

set @CurrentSp=
    (select max(BLSprint)
    from ItemPlan)
execute GetTeamPlanSp @ReleaseID, @CurrentSp
```

**Edit:** `GetTeamPlanSp` contains the line `set nocount on` too.
It seems to be an issue about the assignment of `@CurrentSp`.

Comment: you need to keep updating title and content frequently for getting attention on your question. Some time time is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Query is not executing. When I tried same, I got an error.

```
select @CurrentSp=max(BLSprint) from ItemPlan
execute GetTeamPlanSp @ReleaseID, @CurrentSp
```

Comment: This is the original form I wrote. Same issue. BTW, how did you colorize the code?

Comment: @phoenies: Stack provides this. When writing code see an icon above with some numbers written over there 101 010 . Or use " ` "  symbol to highlight the code. Key just before "1" key